# Adjust vertical spacing in multi column bullet points

Tags: spacing, itemize, multicolumn

I am trying to reduce the vertical space between this multi-column list and the text above and below it. It is for my resume. I have tried using:

```
\setlength\itemsep{-.5em}
```

However, it ends up moving bullet points into different columns.

This is what my code looks like at the moment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins

\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Specalized Coursework}
\begin{multicols}{4}
    \begin{itemize}
   % \setlength\itemsep{-.5em}
        \item Applied Heat \\Transfer
        \item Gas Dynamics
        \item Vibrations
        \item Thermodynamic \\Design
    \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
more info
\end{document}
```

This image might help as well.[image]

Comment: add -2em or a suitable dimension like -2pt -2pcs etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! I'd use the `tasks` package for that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins

\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Specalized Coursework}
\begin{tasks}[label=\textbullet](4)
        \task Applied Heat Transfer
        \task Gas Dynamics
        \task Vibrations
        \task Thermodynamic Design
\end{tasks}
more info
\end{document}
```

[image]

According to the manual, you can change the vertical spacing with `before-skip` and `after-skip` (but for some reason I can only see the impact of `after-skip` at this point).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins

\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{before-skip=0em,after-skip=-0.1em}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Specalized Coursework}
\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](4)
        \task Applied Heat Transfer
        \task Gas Dynamics
        \task Vibrations
        \task Thermodynamic Design
\end{tasks}
more info
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked great! Much easier than combining multi-columns and itemize.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins

\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Specalized Coursework}\\[-2em]%<--------------add
\begin{multicols}{4}
    \begin{itemize}
   % \setlength\itemsep{-.5em}
        \item Applied Heat \\Transfer
        \item Gas Dynamics
        \item Vibrations
        \item Thermodynamic \\Design
    \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
more info
\end{document}
```